# Load Big Data using D3 without performance degradation

Tags: d3.js, reactjs, bigdata, dc.js, crossfilter

I have scenario as follows,

i have a text file, it has 105 millions of data, after aggregation the no: of records will be reduced to 21000-500k, is there a way to use same textfile memory after aggregation and visualize the data using d3.js without performance degradation.

Comment: What do you mean by "use same textfile memory"? Do you have performance problems with the aggregation, with the rendering, with the data loading?

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to query from a big data store and visualize with d3.js. For example, you can connect d3.js and Google BigQuery,[this](http://blog.vida.io/2014/07/06/bigquery-big-data-visualization-with-d3-dot-js/) link could help you.

[This](https://mango-is.com/blog/engineering/pre-render-d3-js-charts-at-server-side/) blog suggests to pre-render D3.js visualizations at server side to increase the performance of D3.js.

Complete explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315054/how-d3-js-handles-millions-of-data/31316430#31316430).